# Возможно ли в C# переопределить порядок выполнения операторов?

Tags: c#

Мне лично приносит некоторые неудобства встроенный порядок выполнения операторов, когда битовые операции имеют более низкий приоритет, чем арифметические. Возможно ли как-то переопределить порядок вычисления операторов для конкретного класса?

```
Пример
Сейчас: 1 ^ 2 + 5 = 1 ^ 7 = 6
Я хочу: 1 ^ 2 + 5 = 3 + 5 = 8
```

Comment: ам, а скобки вас не устроят ?

Comment: Да а что скобки не помогают уже

Comment: Разумеется, если нет способа извратиться и переопределить порядок, то я просто буду использовать скобки, но сама техническая возможность сделать что-то подобное интересна и вне конкретной задачи.

Comment: Зажмурился и представил, какими эпитетами Вас наградят программисты, которым придется сопровождать Вашу программу....

Comment: Для меня когда-то тоже было сюрпризом, что математические операторы имеют приоритет перед бинарными, но потом привык, и вы привыкайте. В целом, ответ на вопрос - **нет**.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов программа моя личная, и она в принципе не будет сопровождаться даже мной, не то, что другими. А вообще я думаю, что люди были бы счастливы, если бы битовые операции имели более высокий порядок, чем арифметические.

Comment: @aepot это прямо категорическое нет? Не существует вообще никаких грязных хаков, позволяющих это сделать? Например, оператор () можно извращенно перегрузить, хотя документация это запрещает.

Comment: Существует грязный хак, конечно, заносите выражение в `string` и пишите свой парсер. А так, выражения парсит Roslyn, у него есть гитхаб, можете форкнуть репозиторий и переписать C# компилятор под себя. Грязнее не придумаешь.

Comment: @aepot звучит, конечно, ужасно, но все-таки это хоть какой-то вариант.

Comment: Это всё круто конечно, а зачем оно вообще надо? Как вам такое `if (a + b & c > 0)`? Представьте, как бы удивился разработчик вашему порядку вычисления этого выражения?

Comment: @aepot ну я лично это выражение воспринимаю как `if ((a + (b & c)) > 0)`, так что я удивляюсь, когда вижу настоящий порядок действий. Я привык, что логическое И пишется как &&, а битовые операции воспринимаю операциями одних из высших порядков.

Comment: Значит ваше восприятие не соответствует действительному положению вещей. Я начинал учить C# в том числе с этой статьи - [Операторы и выражения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence)

Comment: Вместо C# переходите на какой-нибудь другой язык, который позволяет менять синтаксис языка. Их мало, но они есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаю выжимку из сообщений комментаторов, чтобы вопрос не висел неотвеченным:

1. В C# не существует встроенной возможности изменять порядок вычисления операторов. Существующий порядок их вычисления описан в документации по ссылке: [Приоритет операторов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence).
2. Грязные хаки, которые позволяют изменить порядок вычисления операторов существуют, но фактически в разработке не применимы.
3. Для изменения порядка вычисления операторов можно и нужно использовать круглые скобки ().